# is it possible to add a button to the right-click context menu for a user in Outlook 2010 using VBA?

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010

I've tried many things and read up quite a bit but I cannot figure this out.

I cannot create an add-in so I have to use VBA.

I want to add a a button to the right-click context menu when I right-click on a user. Is this possible?

[image: the right-click context menu for a user]

Comment: You can create VBA addin... Please, see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736%28v=office.14%29.aspx

Comment: Here's an SO answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15118033/293078

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create a right-click context menu in Outlook 2003](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15075384/create-a-right-click-context-menu-in-outlook-2003)

Comment: @MaciejLos: I cannot create an add-in.

Comment: @Chrismas007: Outlook 2003 does things very differently then Outlook 2010.

Comment: @DougGlancy: That doesn't work for Outlook 2010. Thanks!

Comment: Woops, sorry. It's too bad they made it so difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to customize the context menu in Outlook. See [Customizing Context Menus in Office 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee691832(v=office.14).aspx) for more information.

But VBA doesn't allow to customize the Fluent UI in Outlook, you need to develop an add-in instead.

Comment: Thing is, even if I edit the `%appdata%\Microsoft\Office\olkexplorer.officeUI` file manually the context menu's do not show up. I would assume I could at least add the buttons manually that way?

Comment: Try to develop an add-in.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot. I guess I'm SOL for now. Thanks!