# Add context menu item in Outlook 2016

Tags: vba, outlook

In outlook 2007 the following code added a menu item to the context menu when a user right clicked a mail item. However in outlook 2016 this does not work. This code is not executed at all.

```
Sub Application_ItemContextMenuDisplay(ByVal CommandBar As Office.CommandBar, ByVal Selection As Selection)
...
End Sub
```

How can i add a right click menu item in outlook 2016 through vba.

Comment: Changes as of Outlook 2010. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28090754/is-it-possible-to-add-a-button-to-the-right-click-context-menu-for-a-user-in-out , https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee691832(v=office.14).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must do that through the Ribbon XML (just like all ribbon controls) - see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee691832(v=office.14).aspx